# Вычисления с элементами массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Всем привет!
У меня возникла небольшая проблема у меня имеется **список** с различными значениями в **хаотичном порядке** содержащим числа от **1 до 9**. Мне нужно сделать проверку, **если 3 значения в результате дадут 15**.
Числа не повторяются и массив не меньше чем три числа.
Это вопрос аналогия поскольку будет использоваться более большие магические квадраты(так и называются - магические).

Я знаю что вопрос очень маленький но мне нечем его дополнить.  :/

Comment: Простейший вариант решения - три вложенных цикла, каждый следующий начинается с индекса текущего элемента предыдущего цикла + 1. Сложить числа по индексам всех трёх циклов, проверить, что это 15, если да - вывести эти индексы. Ну, примерно так, с граничными значениями надо тщательно только разобраться. Всё.

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну это понятно мне нужен более рациональный способ.

Comment: Обязательно должна быть сумма трех элементов или не более трех? То есть для массива [6, 9, 5] ответ [6, 9] или его нет?

Comment: @EzikBro именно трёх, я прост крестики нолики пишу у меня магический квадрат(сумма всех сторон равна 15) и мне нужно сделать данное действие.

Comment: А числа в списке могут повторяться? То есть список [2, 2, 3, 3, 11] может на вход попасть? Тогда ответ [2, 2, 11]?

Comment: @EzikBro нет...

Comment: Ну и в чем тогда проблема? Если числа не повторяются, то их не больше девяти, и тогда алгоритм CrazyElf отработает за 9*8*7/6 операций максимум, если я еще хоть что-то помню про комбу. Если что-то изобретать, и то дольше выйдет, скорее всего.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127680/discussion-between-alex-alexeev-and-ezikbro).

Comment: @EzikBro я ищу более рациональный способ....

Comment: @Alexalexeev вы сейчас пытаетесь купить эскаватор, чтобы вырыть себе маленькую ямку для посадки луковицы.

Comment: @n1tr0xs Да да, данный вопрос я привел как пример далее мне нужно будет заполнять квадраты 4x4 5x5 6x6 и т.д. как уровень сложности игры. ты не понимая что экскаватор будет только опробован на маленький луковице не зная что он будет проводить шахтные работы)

Comment: @n1tr0xs надеюсь ты понимаешь что писать по 5, 6, 7 вложенных циклов не сообразно :/

Comment: Ну тогда и задавали бы вопрос-обобщение сразу, потому что решение для частного случая может совершенно не подходить для общего, как например то, которое я только что написал

Comment: @EzikBro согласен мой прокол.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в обобщенном варианте есть некоторый список, состоящий из некоторых уникальных чисел от 1 до N^2, и нужно выбрать из него N чисел таких, что их сумма равна сумме всех чисел от 1 до N^2, деленной на N (то есть N*(N^2+1)/2)?

Comment: Для такого обобщения можно использовать некоторый аналог решения задачи о рюкзаке, итоговая сложность будет вроде O(N^6) - [сумма]*[кол-во чисел в наборе]*[кол-во чисел в списке]. Если вы подтвердите, что я правильно понял обобщение вашей задачи, то напишу ответ.

Comment: @EzikBro да именно так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написал решение для общего случая:

```
def magic_support(dp, n, s=None, i=None, j=None, last=None):
    if s is None:
        s = n * (n ** 2 + 1) // 2
        i, j = n, s
        last = s + 1

    elif i == 0:
        yield []
        return
    
    for item in dp[i][j]:
        if item >= last:
            break
        for res in magic_support(dp, n, s, i - 1, j - item, item):
            yield res + [item]


def magic(a, n):
    a.sort()
    s = n ** 2 * (n ** 2 + 1) // 2 // n # 3: 15, 4: 34
    
    dp = [[[] for _ in range(s + 1)] for _ in range(n + 1)]
    dp[0][0] = [0]
    for item in a:
        for layer in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
            for weight in range(s - item + 1):
                if dp[layer][weight]:
                    dp[layer + 1][weight + item].append(item)
    
    return magic_support(dp, n)


n = 4
a = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13]
for i in magic(a, n):
    print(i)
# [5, 7, 10, 12]
# [5, 6, 10, 13]
# [3, 6, 12, 13]
```

В основе алгоритма лежит [ДП-решение задачи о рюкзаке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Только в данном случае предметы не имеют никакой ценности, вычисляется только принципиальная возможность собрать рюкзак определенного веса. `dp[layer][weight]` отвечает на вопрос, возможно ли собрать сумму `weight` из `layer` предметов. В каждой ячейке массива `dp` хранится список из чисел, используя которые можно ее достичь. Благодаря этому, возможно восстановить "путь", которым была собрана сумма `s`.

Функция `magic` работает за O(N^6), но количество путей растет очень быстро. В массиве оно хранится достаточно сжато, но я за полчаса так и не дошел до конца генератора при N=20. Знаю лишь то, что при N=11, все двадцать миллионов комбинаций перебирались две минуты.

Перебор для малых значений N, по моему мнению, проще всего пишется так:

```
from itertools import combinations

n = 4
s = 34
a = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13]
for comb in combinations(a, n):
    if sum(comb) == s:
        print(*comb)
# 3 6 12 13
# 5 6 10 13
# 5 7 10 12
```

Но это решение не оптимально по своей скорости, поэтому я попробовал написать рекурсивный перебор с отсечением ветвей:

```
def rec(a, n, s=None, count=0, last=-1, summ=0, way=None):
    if count == 0:
        a.sort()
        s = n * (n ** 2 + 1) // 2
        way = []
        
    elif count == n:
        if summ == s:
            yield way
        return

    elif summ + (n - count) * a[last] > s:
        return
    
    for i in range(last + 1, len(a) - n + count + 1):
        way.append(a[i])
        yield from rec(a, n, s, count + 1, i, summ + a[i], way)
        way.pop()


n = 4
a = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13]
for i in rec(a, n):
    print(i)
# [3, 6, 12, 13]
# [5, 6, 10, 13]
# [5, 7, 10, 12]
```

Comment: спасибо тебе!  :D

Comment: ей а можешь подсказать как сделать так что бы он находил все возможные комбинации.

Comment: @Alexalexeev переделал решение, теперь выдает все комбинации. Возможно завтра еще отредактирую код, потому что сейчас сонный и не уверен до конца.

Answer (score 3):

Ладно, вот вам более рациональный способ:

```
def magic(a):
    in_a = [False] * 10
    for i in a:
        in_a[i] = True
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
            x = 15 - a[i] - a[j]
            if x > 0 and in_a[x] and x != a[i] and x != a[j]:
                return [a[i], a[j], x]
    return []

print(magic([2, 4, 9, 1, 6]))
# [2, 4, 9]
```

То есть для любых двух чисел в списке вычисляется число, которого им недостает до 15, после чего проверяется, есть ли это число в списке и не было ли оно использовано в текущем наборе.

Работает не за N^3/6 как в полностью переборном алгоритме, а за N^2/2, но в вашем случае (размер массива до девяти) выигрыш будет не более, чем в два раза.

Answer (score 1):

Общий подход для любого кол-ва элементов/размера пачки для суммы/суммы.

```
import typing as t
import random

def magic(array: list, cnt: int, sum_: int) -> t.List[list]:
    """

    :param array:  массив элементов
    :param cnt:  размер пачки элементов для проверки
    :param sum_:  суммма пачки которая делает ее "магической"
    :return: массив магических пачек.
    """
    result = []
    if len(array) < cnt:
        raise ValueError("Список меньше заданного кол-ва чисел.")

    slice_count = len(array) - cnt + 1
    chunks = [
        array[i:i + cnt]
        for i in range(slice_count)
    ]

    for chunk in chunks:
        if sum(chunk) == sum_:
            result.append(chunk)

    return result


arr = [1, 2, 7, 9, 5, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3]
print([[1, 2, 7], [2, 5, 3], [5, 3, 2], [4, 1, 5]] == magic(arr, 3, 10)) # out: True
print([[2, 7, 9, 5, 2]] == magic(arr, 5, 25))  # out: True

arr_2 = [1, 3, 5, 11, 9, 7, 14, 6, 8, 12]

for i in magic(arr_2, 2, 20):
    print(f"Magic chunk - {i}")
# out: Magic chunk - [11, 9]
#      Magic chunk - [14, 6]
#      Magic chunk - [8, 12]
arr_3 = [random.randint(x, x * 2 - x % 2) for x in range(1_000_000)]

start = datetime.now()
for i in magic(arr_3, 8, 124):
    print(f"Magic chunk - {i}")
print(f'get magic for {datetime.now() - start}')
# out:
#Magic chunk - [8, 16, 17, 10, 16, 22, 14, 21]
#get magic for 0:00:00.736550
```

Единственное, не стал заморачиваться с проверкой на уникальные значения, алгоритм не изменится - можете добавить сами в начале функции. Скорость зависит от `cnt`. Чем выше тем меньше пачек, но дольше занимает сумма элементов. + При очень больших значениях и большом `cnt` я бы вынес формирование пачек в отдельную функцию с генератором что бы не хранить их в памяти, да и сам результат если предполагается много магических последовательностей лучше генерировать..

Comment: спасибо большое!)